# i have some problem when importing module in main.js file in browser

Tags: node.js, import, module, axios

Showing error in console (Browser ):
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at main.js:1:1)`

**But i have installed all module **
this type error showing when importing `axios`

this is main.js code :

```
import axios from 'axios'
let addToCart= document.querySelectorAll('.add-to-cart');

function  updateCart(pizza){_
 // axios  like as ajax 
    axios.post('/update-cart',pizza).then(res=>{
        console.log(res);
    })
}

addToCart.forEach((btn)=>{
    btn.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
       // console.log(e)
        let pizza =JSON.parse( btn.dataset.pizza); //get data attribute value
        updateCart(pizza);
    })
})
```

here is my package.json :

```
 "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "connect-mongo": "^4.6.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "ejs": "^3.1.8",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "express-ejs-layouts": "^2.5.1",
    "express-flash": "^0.0.2",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "mongoose": "^6.4.1"
  }
```

[You can see  in this photo what the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9j956.png)

index.html page code :

```
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <script type="module" src="/js/main.js"></script>
```

How to fix it.

Comment: you can see here screenshot : https://i.postimg.cc/Gp8kGQwJ/image.png

Answer (score 0):

**Loading Axios from CDN**

- Add a reference to the Axios library in your script tag in your HTML code.
  For instance

```html
<!-- Axios via CDN -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<!-- The code loading axios -->
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

- Remove the import statement, as Axios is loaded as a global object

main.js

```js
// import axios from 'axios' <= Remove this
```

---

**Loading Axios from NPM, ESM version**

I tested their library. Only their alpha version seems to be ESM compatible. If you want to use this alpha version:

Install Axios:

```bash
npm install axios@1.0.0-alpha.1
```

HTML

```html
<!-- The code loading axios -->
<script src="main.js" type="module"></script>
```

main.js

```js
// The path to their ESM version in the node_modules package is /node_modules/axios/dist/esm/axios.js, so you have to update the import accordingly.
import axios from "/axios/dist/esm/axios.js";   // relative or absolute path

// your code ...
```

I quickly tested locally—all fine.

Comment: i have added but can't load

Comment: Sorry, I edited my answer. I just checked the Axios library on npmjs.com, the CDN version of their library makes the "axios" object globally accessible. You don't need the import statement.

Comment: I also added the process to load the Axios ESM version. The ESM version "export" the "axios" object, which make it possible to use the "import" statement.

Comment: Not  fine. showing this error :   GET http://localhost:3000/axios/dist/esm/axios.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

Comment: here is code screenshot : https://i.postimg.cc/Gp8kGQwJ/image.png

Comment: @Sujeetkumar, I am not sure of your server configuration. The path needs to be adapted to work locally.
Try this import in main.js to make the import simpler: 
```import axios from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/axios";```

Answer (score 0):

I see u use express so u have a public folder to insert css and js in it .. and u use ejs to server side rendering for the html
The problem here u cannot use *import* and *require* in the same project
So u have 2 solutions depend on case.
1- simply for axios u can use cdn version and everythings will be fine
2- it's your case .. cause u use import for the *index.js* file
The solution for that is use a bundler
There is many like *webpack* but it is complex for your situation
So i recommed you to use *parcel-bundler* it is zero configuration and very simple .. u only need to install it from npm and write the command to run it .. u need to run the bundler always with your project.
Hope that answer your question